# How can I use calc to convert in orgmode table

Tags: org-mode, org-table, calc

I am trying to use calc convert in an org mode table.
The gnu manual suggests
`$c/$1/$cm`
So in my table I tried (for column formula
`=$c/$1/$cm` also tried `=$1/$c/$cm`, `=$1/$m/$cm` etc
Which produces `#ERROR`. Ideally I would like to convert rpm to rad/s, but converting any units for now would be great.

My data is a float with no units in the cell fyi.

Example

```
|  rpm | rads   |
|------+--------|
| 9500 | #ERROR |
|   95 | #ERROR |
|   95 | #ERROR |
#+TBLFM: @2$2=$1/$rpm/$rad/s::@3$2=$cm/$1/$m::@4$2=$1/$cm/$m
```

(row 1 would be the ideal behaivor, but id be happy if i could get row 2 or 3 to work)

Comment: I think you're going to have to clarify your question a bit. Try making a small table and including an actual formula that you've tried, then describe the results you want to achieve for that example.

Comment: The example does not make sense: in the first formula `$1` is 9500 but what is `$rpm` and what is `$rad`? What exactly are you trying to convert and what are you trying to convert it to?

Comment: Based on the following ‘$c/$1/$cm’ Hz → cm conversion, using ‘constants.el’   https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html#Formula-syntax-for-Calc